# how to create a custom discount “Gift card” in my website at cart page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

The functionality will be =

1. Enter Gift Card number(16 digit)
2. Enter Gift Card Pin(6 digit)
3. Enter Amount(amount entered by user)

I have already created the above mentioned input fields in the cart page.but dont know how to proceed further.

website: https://www.happyvalleytea.com/

cart page view: https://www.happyvalleytea.com/checkout/cart/ (add any product to cart)

when the user clicks on gift card apply button, the transaction will happen on a 3rd party vendor(via curl api call).
The response received from the api should be used as a discount amount on the cart page.

Comment: is it magento2 or magento1? you should clean up the tags

Comment: @PhilippSander it is magento 1.9.3.2